# Classical Green function

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, greens-functions

What is the physical reason why the classical Green's function is not defined as a principle value integral?

In a recent discussion ([Classical Green's function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/406047/classical-greens-function)) it was said that the classical Green function (as an example the retarded one): $G_{R}(x-x') = \frac{\delta(x^{0}-x'^{0} -R)}{4 \pi R}$
dove $R=|{\vec{x} - \vec{x'}}|$ is obtained by choosing for the integral a contour with an infinitesimal damping and not by taking the principal value of the integral on the real axis which would lead to another form of the Green's function. What is the physical reason to choose one contour or the other, if there is any?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution to the differential equation for the Green's function can
be used. If you solve for the Green's function using contour integration
over the frequencies, the solutions for the portion of the contour
near the pole are solutions of the homogeneous wave equation. Choosing
different contours corresponds to adding different solutions to the
homogeneous wave equation and therefore give different boundary conditions.
You could also find these solutions using other methods to
solve the differential equation without contour integration.

The reason to choose various boundary conditions is that when you use
Green's theorem to write the desired solution, you have terms where
you integrate over the source, and terms which come from the
space-time surface. If you can choose the boundary conditions for your
Green's function so that the surface terms are zero, your calculation
becomes simpler.
Every Green's function gives one particular solution.
Choosing the
retarded Green's function will make the time surface terms zero if the
fields are all zero before the source turns on. Often this is the solution
you want. Other boundary conditions solve other cases directly.